# как рассчитать угол а

Tags: физика

снаряд летит из точки A в точку B со скоростью V под углом a с длительностью T также известно ускорение свободного падения G .

Известны точки A и B время T скорость V и ускорение свободного падения G ,как рассчитать угол а

Comment: `a = arccos((B-A)/(V*T))` какое это имеет отношение к программированию?

Comment: снаряд летит  из точки A в точку B

Comment: формула работает, пример: [`math.degrees(math.acos(13.95/(20*4.02))) == 80`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Vvr.png). Можно и [другие значения попробовать](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/projectile-motion/latest/projectile-motion_en.html)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию. Это домашняя работа по физике.

Comment: @AK, а может это для игрушки нада, типа танков :-D

Comment: это нужно было для расчета траектории полета снаряда

Answer (score 1):

Из курса физики 8, что ли, класса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше сами сообразите?

Comment: у меня так позиция рассчитывается

Comment: тут уже известен угол , а мне его еще найти надо

Comment: Так вы еще скажете, что в квадратном уравнении x известен... Выведите его из этих уравнений, других для вас Ньютон не придумал. Есть еще Эйнштейновы, но вряд ли они вас обрадуют :)

Comment: @Harry зато меня обрадуют! пишите. Желательно в дифференциальной форме с учётом сопротивления, чтобы получить угол в 53 градуса и длину полёта Колоссаль.

Comment: @pavel У меня есть поистине чудесное решение этой задачи, но поле комментария слишком мало, чтобы его вместить...

Comment: @Harry Молодец! Sapienti sat.